# Stretch window across two screens in windowed mode

Tags: virtualbox, vmware-player

This question is specific to making one guest "screen", in windowed mode, wide enough to span two physical monitors on the host. I know how to get two guest screens in Virtualbox (easy!) or in VMware (less convenient, but doable with full screen mode).

Anyone know how to make this happen? I want to basically stretch one window to cover two monitors. The guest screen would then have a resolution like 3800x1080, and the single window which contains said guest then spans two monitors which each have 1900x1200 resolution.

Adjusting the resolution in the guest didn't do it; changing resolution manually in VMware graphics settings didn't do it; manually stretching the window just makes it automatically snap the window to cover just one host monitor.

Primary difference from [VirtualBox single guest screen splits across two host monitors](https://superuser.com/questions/829950/virtualbox-single-guest-screen-splits-across-two-host-monitors) is that I want the guest to run in windowed mode.

Answer (score -1):

With virtual box, you can stretch across 2 monitors with version 4.3.12. I haven't updated virtual box since then because they broke this feature.